# On the mandatory IRS audit of sitting president and vice-president

Tags: united-states, president, vice-president

It's been [reported](https://money.cnn.com/2017/04/17/news/economy/president-audit-trump/index.html) that the sitting president and vice president are subject to mandatory IRS audit.

Two questions regarding this:

1. Is there some statutory authority that requires the IRS to conduct these audits, and if not, what is the reasoning that compels the IRS to perform these audits?
2. When the IRS conducts these audits (of the president and vice president), does the IRS check on the legality or propriety of financial activities that are reported? (I'm thinking violations of emoluments clause, earnings from foreign entities, personal cash paid out to foreign entities, *etc.*)

Comment: The formal requirement [is available from the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/irm/part4/irm_04-008-004#idm139728253070352), though at the moment I don't know if this is required *by statute* or is simply an internal policy that could, in principle, be arbitrarily revoked by executive branch actors.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: [it's an internal policy](https://www.grassley.senate.gov/news/news-releases/grassley-requests-president-s-tax-returns).

Comment: @zibadawa timmy - interesting reading,  (IRM), but haven't found any statutory authority cited. BTW, wasn't aware that presidential tax returns are preserved by the National Archives.